# Change color of picture in Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, image, colors

I have `.png` picture in `Excel`. I'd like to change the color of picture by `Macro`.

I am using this code to change colortype:
         `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 12")).PictureFormat.ColorType = 
    msoPictureGrayscale`

I'd like to change `color` of the picture to `RGB color`. I have many pictures and I like to change color for each dynamically, so other tools do not suit for me.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this, with .pngs generated outside Excel.  An alternative option is to create several pngs (`STAR_RED`, `STAR_BLACK`, etc) and dynamically switch images as needed.

Comment: In real case scenario shape is complex and it's not possible to make it using shapes

Comment: The [Excel object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194068.aspx) does not expose all of Excel's functionality.  This is why you can do it manually, but see nothing in the macro recorder.  If it was anywhere I would expect to see it in the [shape object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835842.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the way how to do this.

1. You can take `.svg` picture which is also vectorial.
2. Convert `.svg` to `.emf`.
3. Import `.emf` into Excel

`.emf` file is supported by Excel and has same features a you draw by using shapes.